# Why does my c-lightning node pay more than the invoice plus routing fees?

Tags: transaction-fees, lightning-network, core-lightning

A friend sent me an invoice for 500,000 Satoshis. To my surprise, I sent 502294 Satoshis.

Here's what I see from my c-lightning console:

- "msatoshi": 500,000,000
- "msatoshi_sent": 502,294,595

My friend received a different amount on lnd:

- "value": "500000"
- "amt_paid_sat": "501791"

Any reasons why I am not sending the amount requested on the invoice? Also is my understanding correct that I paid 503 satoshis in fees for this transaction? It's more than I expected on the lightning network.

Thanks,

Francois

Answer (score 4):

In your c-lightning node you have configured your `maximum fee rate` which is used by the `pay` command to do the payment.

The [BOLT04](https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lightning-rfc/blob/master/04-onion-routing.md#failure-messages) describes how overpaying up to twice the amount to obfuscate payments in order to have better privacy is part of the protocol:

> if the amount paid is more than twice the amount expected:
>   SHOULD fail the HTLC.
>
> SHOULD return an incorrect_or_unknown_payment_details error.
>
> Note: this allows the origin node to reduce information leakage by altering the amount while not allowing for accidental gross overpayment.

In combination with [this merged pull request](https://github.com/ElementsProject/lightning/pull/1257) c-lightning fixed [this issue](https://github.com/ElementsProject/lightning/issues/1089)
implementing random overpayments up to the maximum fee rate.

So generally c-lightning will randomly overpay your transaction with an amount that is lower to the maximum feerate you are willing to pay.

Not that [in earlier days lnd did not accept overpayments](https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lnd/issues/1002) as they seemed to not have implemented this part of the protocol.

Comment: Thank you Rene! Is this a way to know the fees paid by each routing node? 503 Satoshis in routing fees seems like an amount that is higher than I expected. Happy to see a fee market develop for LN though!